# Pasar parámetros del Menú Lateral a la Pagina

Tags: angularjs-2.0, ionic, ionic3

estoy en el menu lateral y no puedo pasar datos con el navparams porque no esta en el archivo app.component al intentar agregarlo me sale este error NO PROVIDER FOR NAV CONTROLLER!

(lo que hago es cargo mis tags en el menú lateral y quiero pasar los datos del menú a la pagina por-categoría-page).

¿Alguna otra forma para pasar los datos? algún documento que me recomienden o solución a este error?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Agregaste NavController a tu app.module, en el arreglo de "providers" ?

Answer (score 1):

`NavController` no esta disponible en `app.component`.

Puedes usar [@ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) para acceder al `Nav` cual es la extensión de `NavController`

Ejemplo:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MenuController, Platform, Nav } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component( {
    templateUrl: 'app.html',
} )
export class MyApp {

    @ViewChild( Nav ) nav: Nav;

    .... 

    this.nav.setRoot( AlgunaPagina );    
}
```

Comment: Lo que sucede es que yo estaba enviado los parámetros que estan en un array de mi app.html (menú lateral así..): [navPush]="TagsPage" [navParams]="{ item: tags } pero como no puedo usar el navController, no se como puedo lograrlo, me ayudarias u orientarías un poco?

Comment: @EdwinAnaya - Podrías usar algo como `this.nav.push(TagsPage, {
    item: tags });` No se realmente lo que quieres conseguir pero puedes tener problema (back button) al usar `push()` en vez de `setRoot()` en la clase `MyApp`

Comment: Cargue mi menú lateral con una lista de categorías quiero mostrar una pagina con la lista de productos por la categoría que seleccione en el menú como puedo lograrlo? se hacerlo desde una pagina pasando parámetros por nav params, pero como aqui no se puede pasar con nav params no se hacerlo.

Comment: Mira este [código](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-conference-app/blob/master/src/app/app.component.ts) por ejemplo... y si puedes usar navparams..porque no?

Comment: @EdwinAnaya - Te dejo otro link: [guide-to-navigation](https://www.joshmorony.com/a-simple-guide-to-navigation-in-ionic-2/)